# Why @Stateless @WebService is stateful?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, stateless, stateful

With a web service defined like @Stateless

```
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;
 import javax.jws.WebService;

 @Stateless
 @WebService(serviceName = "TestService")
 public class TestService {
     int counter = 0;
     public int getCounter() {
         return counter++;
     }
 }
```

Why 'counter' is increased with each request and does not return always 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with `@Stateless` you're telling the container that **you are not holding any state**, but you do hold state.

With `@Stateless` the container only creates one instance of the bean, because there's no need to create more.

You might want to read a bit more about JEE and what the annotations mean: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/ejb3/session-beans/slsb/introduction-11/

Comment: The given link helped to understand it better. Thank you. Especially than i modified `getCounter` method with `Thread.sleep` for easy way to get concurrent access.
About "With `@Stateless` the container only creates one instance of the bean, because there's no need to create more" - different instances created in case of such concurrent access.